# Writing a unit test for component which uses router-outlet

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, router-outlet

Anyone know why I'm getting the error at bottom of question trying to instantiate a component which uses `<router-outlet>`?

`console.log('then');` is not getting called, so perhaps the compile is having issues?

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

app.component.html

```
<a id="newPage" routerLink="/new-page">New page</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { PageDetailsComponent } from './new-page/page-details.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'new-page', component: PageDetailsComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { routes } from './app-routing.module';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PageDetailsComponent } from './page-details/page-details.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {

  let component: AppComponent;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    console.log('as');
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)],
      declarations: [AppComponent, PageDetailsComponent]
    }).compileComponents().then(() => {
      console.log('then');
      const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });
  }));

  it('should create an instance of AppComponent', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Error I'm seeing:

```
11 06 2017 09:24:58.055:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket pAXmtnKm0A2IT8ZcAAAA with id 17069837
LOG: 'as'
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) AppComponent should create an instance of AppComponent FAILED
    invokeTask@/tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-10912v4sMPp2rIrzg.js:793:36
    onInvokeTask@/tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-10912v4sMPp2rIrzg.js:2908:49
    invokeTask@/tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-10912v4sMPp2rIrzg.js:792:48
    runTask@/tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-10912v4sMPp2rIrzg.js:560:57
    drainMicroTaskQueue@/tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-10912v4sMPp2rIrzg.js:953:42
    run@/tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-10912v4sMPp2rIrzg.js:20781:29
    /tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-10912v4sMPp2rIrzg.js:20794:31
    flush@/tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-10912v4sMPp2rIrzg.js:20643:11
    resolvePromise@/tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-10912v4sMPp2rIrzg.js:1140:78
    resolvePromise@/tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-10912v4sMPp2rIrzg.js:1110:31
    /tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-10912v4sMPp2rIrzg.js:1187:31
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.068 secs / 0.082 secs)
```

Comment: Try adding `schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]` to `TestBed ` configuration. It will ignore any errors that occur due to child components.

Comment: @AmitChigadani still doesn't log `console.log('then');`, same error

Comment: PhantomJS is known for swallowing the errors from beforeEach. It's not possible to say what's wrong without error message. Try to switch to Chrome. Any way, units should be tested in isolation in unit tests. I don't see why router is necessary in this test, and PageDetailsComponent is absolutely unneeded. You can stub router-outlet and routerLink.